# Angular -Sort nested table

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with nested table
Example data:

```
$scope.building =
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "first",
        "ownBlock": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Block 1"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Block 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "second",
        "ownBlock": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Block 1"
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Block 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

When I sort ownBlock of id 2 , It will sort child data of Id 1 too

```
<tr ng-repeat="block in data.ownBlock| orderBy : sortColumn.Field : sortColumn.Order">.... </tr>
```

I know the reason but I dont have solution to fix that . Hope it helps

Comment: What actual sort order do you want in your data?

Comment: do you want the child data not to be sorted ?

Comment: Thank for your answers , I want to sort child data bro . But my issue is when I sort child data which has parent Id 2 name "second" , child data of id 1 name first is sorted too , i dont want that , i just want only child data of id 2 is sorted

Answer (score 2):

if you dont want the child to be sorted try this

```
$scope.building = $filter('orderBy')($scope.building,'id');
```